# Using sass function with !important

Tags: sass, bulma

I'm using [Bulma CSS framework](https://bulma.io) and they use **!important** on some color styles.

Basically it has this:

```
.has-text-grey-light {
  color: #b5b5b5 !important;
}
```

I wanted to override that color on hover like this in my SASS file:

```
.content ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    li{
        a{
            &.has-text-grey-light:hover{
                color: lighten($grey-light, 15%) !important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the **!important** rule makes it fail to compile. Any idea if we can use **!important** with SCSS functions?

Comment: which sass engine do you use to compile? I did a quick test with online compiler: https://www.sassmeister.com and it works without errors.

Comment: What error do you get? It should work.

Comment: stupid Me! it was because I had put the wrong color format and not because of !important. But being in rush, I didn't read it fully and just assumed it was because of !important. It's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stupid Me! it was because I had put the wrong color format and not because of **!important**. But being **in a rush**, I didn't read it fully and just assumed it was because of **!important**. It's working now.